# EMGU CV real time Eye tracking using C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-detection, eye-tracking

I am following Luca Del Tongo tutorial on youtube in order to track the eyes from face. I managed to do so using rectangle but I would like to track it using HoughCircle.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07QAhRJmcKQ

I am using the following code to track my eyes and it is creating multiple circles around my eyes. [image]
I only converted the image to gray scale as he told us to do in the tutorial.  Can you please help? I am new to EMGU CV

```
grayFrame.ROI = possibleROI_leftEye;
                MCvAvgComp[][] leftEyesDetected = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(_eyes, 1.15, 0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
                grayFrame.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                grayFrame.ROI = possibleROI_rightEye;
                MCvAvgComp[][] rightEyesDetected = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(_eyes, 1.15, 0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20));
                grayFrame.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                //If we are able to find eyes inside the possible face, it should be a face, maybe we find also a couple of eyes
                if (leftEyesDetected[0].Length != 0 && rightEyesDetected[0].Length != 0)
                {
                    //draw the face
                    frame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Violet), 2);


                    #region Hough Circles Eye Detection

                    grayFrame.ROI = possibleROI_leftEye;
                    CircleF[] leftEyecircles = grayFrame.HoughCircles(new Gray(180), new Gray(70), 5.0, 10.0, 1, 200)[0];
                    grayFrame.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
                    foreach (CircleF circle in leftEyecircles)
                    {
                        float x = circle.Center.X + startingLeftEyePointOptimized.X;
                        float y = circle.Center.Y + startingLeftEyePointOptimized.Y;
                        frame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), circle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
                    }

                    grayFrame.ROI = possibleROI_rightEye;
                    CircleF[] rightEyecircles = grayFrame.HoughCircles(new Gray(180), new Gray(70), 2.0, 20.0, 1, 5)[0];
                    grayFrame.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                    foreach (CircleF circle in rightEyecircles)
                    {
                        float x = circle.Center.X + startingPointSearchEyes.X;
                        float y = circle.Center.Y + startingPointSearchEyes.Y;
                        frame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), circle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
                    }

                    #endregion
```

---

Now I changed the part where it finds the eyes to

```
 grayImageFrame.ROI = possibleROI_leftEye;
                CircleF[] leftEyecircles = grayImageFrame.HoughCircles(new Gray(180), new Gray(70), 5.0, 10.0, 1, 20)[0];
                if (leftEyecircles.Length > 0)
                {
                    CircleF firstCircle = leftEyecircles[0]; // Pick first circle in list
                    float x = firstCircle.Center.X + startingPointSearchEyes.X;
                    float y = firstCircle.Center.Y + startingPointSearchEyes.Y;
                    ImageFrame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), firstCircle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
                }
                grayImageFrame.ROI = possibleROI_rightEye;
                CircleF[] rightEyecircles = grayImageFrame.HoughCircles(new Gray(180), new Gray(70), 5.0, 10.0, 1, 20)[0];
                grayImageFrame.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                if (rightEyecircles.Length > 0)
                {
                    CircleF firstCircle = rightEyecircles[0]; // Pick first circle in list
                    float x = firstCircle.Center.X + startingPointSearchEyes.X;
                    float y = firstCircle.Center.Y + startingPointSearchEyes.Y;
                    ImageFrame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), firstCircle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
                }
```

Only one circle is showing but it is tracking parts around my eyes not my eyes :(

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am trying to use HoughCircle in order to detect my eyes. But it is creating multiple circles around my eyes. :( I would like some one to help me in order to get only one circle around the eye

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get multiple circles is simply because you are drawing all found circles with this for-loop

```
foreach (CircleF circle in rightEyecircles)
{
    float x = circle.Center.X + startingPointSearchEyes.X;
    float y = circle.Center.Y + startingPointSearchEyes.Y;
    frame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), circle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
}
```

To draw only one circle, you must pick a single circle from the list (or possibly a composite estimate formed by a number of circles) and draw only that.

I am not really a C# guy, but I guess something like this would work

```
CircleF firstCircle = rightEyecircles[0]; // Pick first circle in list
float x = firstCircle.Center.X + startingPointSearchEyes.X;
float y = firstCircle.Center.Y + startingPointSearchEyes.Y;
frame.Draw(new CircleF(new PointF(x, y), firstCircle.Radius), new Bgr(Color.RoyalBlue), 4);
```

Comment: The circle is appearing near my eyes I will update the question image. T

Comment: That is probably because the first circle is not the best circle. You need to do something to make sure that the circle you choose is the one you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Hannes, I think this can be done using image processing methods to remove the amount of detections you receive, rather than just drawing one of the found circles.

1. Apply a Gaussian blur to reduce noise and avoid false circle detection:

   GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );
2. Apply a min/max circle radius to the Hough Transform

   min_radius = 0: Minimum radio to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default.

   max_radius = 0: Maximum radius to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default

Comment: To be fair, I answered the question *"Why am I getting multiple circles?"*. Finding the best circle is a much more difficult problem. Your suggestions sound good though, so your answer is probably more useful than mine :)

Comment: Aye, I suppose it depends what the asker wants from the solution. You just beat me to an answer ;)

Comment: I don't know why the Blur is closing my appliction

Answer (score 0):

For detecting one eye ball in the specific region perform following tasks

*1- Use haarcascade to detect eye and select ROI of that eye and detect hough circle there.

2- convert into gray image

3- threshold the image*

```
 grayFrame._ThresholdBinary(new Gray(33), new Gray(255));
```

4- *now find eye ball from hough circles.*

Happy coding.